# TypeError: Body is undefined and cannot read property

Tags: node.js, rest

I am creating a Restful API using node and postgres. I am currently creating a POST function and am having some problems with it. Right now, I am trying to test my function but I encounter what seems to be an undefined request body.

```
 57 function createAction(req, res) { 
 58   pool.connect(function(err,client,done) {
 59     if(err){
 60       console.log("Not able to get connection "+ err + "\n");
 61       res.status(400).send(err);
 62     }
 63     
 64     req.body.otherKey = parseInt(req.body.otherKey); // ERROR HERE
 65     client.query('INSERT INTO acts(dateDone, completed, otherKey)'
 66     + 'values(${dateDone}, ${completed}, ${otherKey})',
 67     req.body, function(err,res) {
 68       
 69       done();
 70       if(err){
 71         console.log(err);
 72         res.status(400).send(err);
 73       }
 74       
 75       res.status(200);
 76       console.log("Successfully created new action");
 77     });
 78   });
 79 }
```

I am testing it with the following code:

```
curl -d "dateDone=testPOST&completed=f&otherKey=100" http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/actions
```

The error message is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'otherKey' of undefined
```

Comment: try to add `-X POST` to curl

Comment: @VasylMoskalov just tried it, same error

Comment: Try using req.query instead of req.body.

Comment: Have you analytic `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in your code just like `body-parser` library do.

Comment: @MiguelCalderón That solved this error, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. URL query variables are stored in req.query ;)

Answer (score 0):

req.body is not defined because the "body" is not parsed.
use the middleware `body-parser` https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Or you can manually define a wrapper.

```
function postWrapper(req, res, cb) {
  req.on('data', function(data) {
    if (!req.body) {
      req.body = '';
    }
    req.body += data.toString();
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    cb(req, res);
  });
}
```

and then:

```
function createAction(req, res) {
    postWrapper(req, res, function(req, res){
        // your code
    }
}
```